# Using SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty with SPDRP_HARDWAREID

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn

The docs for the [SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function say,

> The following values are reserved for use by the operating system and
>   **cannot be used** in the Property parameter ...
>   SPDRP_HARDWAREID

However, there are lots of examples of code out there, including [MS DevCon](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/DevCon-Sample-4e95d71c/view/SourceCode) utility which uses this function with the SPDRP_HARDWAREID parameter, ie:

> SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty(DeviceInfoSet, 
>           &DeviceInfoData, 
>           SPDRP_HARDWAREID, 
>           (LPBYTE)hwIdList, 
>           (lstrlen(hwIdList)+1+1)*sizeof(TCHAR)))

They also have an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543686%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which suggests doing so:

> If an installer detects a non-PnP device, the installer should select a driver for the device as follows: create a device information element (SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo), set the SPDRP_HARDWAREID property by calling SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty

I'd like to (and do) use this function to set Hardware ID for my virtual device. The question is - is it a typo in the manual, or it's some sort of unsupported behavior and therefore it can stop working any time?

Comment: I would recommend that you use it only when following specific instructions from Microsoft, such as the article you reference.

Comment: I do so, but it's still confusing. Just trying to do things right, to avoid surprises in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: If you're creating a **root-enumerated device** node, you're free to set `SPDRP_HARDWAREID`/`SPDRP_COMPATIBLEIDS` yourself by calling `SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty`. Otherwise you're not allowed to do so.

---

This *was* an error in the docs that was fixed at some point.

Today the docs of [`SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552169(v=vs.85).aspx) read:

> SPDRP_HARDWAREID or SPDRP_COMPATIBLEIDS **can only be used when DeviceInfoData represents a root-enumerated device**. For other devices, the bus driver reports hardware and compatible IDs when enumerating a child device after receiving IRP_MN_QUERY_ID. *[Emphasis mine]*

... which is exactly what DevCon does.